# R Markdown not showing ggplot when knit

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I'm probably overlooking something very simple.  When I knit the following

````
---
title: "Clarity vs Color"
output: html_document
params:
  cut: "Ideal"
---

```{r include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)

data(diamonds)

clarity <- diamonds %>% select(cut, price, carat, clarity)  %>% filter(cut == params$cut)

outputPlot <- clarity %>% ggplot(aes(x=carat, y=price)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = clarity)) +
  labs(title ="Clarity vs Color",
       x="Diamond Clarity",y="Diamond Color")  

print(outputPlot)

```
````

I get a document with a title but no plot.
If I construct the clarity dataframe manually however, by simply substituting a value of "Ideal" for `params$cut` and then run

```
outputPlot <- clarity %>% ggplot(aes(x=carat, y=price)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = clarity)) +
  labs(title ="Clarity vs Color",
       x="Diamond Clarity",y="Diamond Color")  

print(outputPlot)
```

at the console, I get the plot I'm expecting

[image]

So why is it not showing up in my output document?

[image]

Comment: you have `include=FALSE`

Comment: Can I delete my account now?   SMH